# .Net Core .Count() does not work with IQueryable with Distinct() filter

Tags: linq, .net-core, count, iqueryable

Creating an `IQueryable` with `.Distinct()` If you try to apply `query.Count()` like for a paginator solution is not working but yes without `.Distinct()`.

When I am using

```
var totalItems = query.Count();
```

with the `.Distinct()`, I am get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

Such a fix, I applied this conversion and where if I have to Distinct just make the count from an `IEnumerable` and if not just do it normally

```
private static int Count(IQueryable<A> query, Option<B> distinctByOption)
{
    return distinctByOption.Match(_ => ToListCount(query), query.Count);
}  

private static int ToEnumerableCount(IEnumerable<A> enumerable)
{   
    return enumerable.Count();      
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please spend more time on your question to explain what you are excepting to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: What code do you have? What exact issue are you seeing?

Comment: I do not see here EF. Just IEnumerable

Comment: Show code which do not work. Your patches are not relevant.

Comment: Corrected @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Where is your query? `query.Dsitinct().Count()` should work. So then you have something nontranslatable.